# Access text box content that is dynamically declared in C#

Tags: c#

The code will dynamically create a number of text boxes in C# winform depending on my data. How can I now work on this text box before I execute the code? In other words, in the second button below, how can I access data of all the text boxes?

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // first button to create textboxes
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.ColumnCount; i++)
            {

                TextBox t1 = new TextBox(); this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(t1); 
                t1.Name= "text" + i;
                t1.Location = new Point(i+30, i +25); 

            }
        }

 private void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// second button to manipulate text boxes
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
               if(t1.text=="sunny") {\\.......}

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
private void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        string textBoxName = "text" + i;
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)Controls["text0"];

        if (textBox.Text == "sunny")
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

`Controls[key]` retrieves child control of form with name `key`.